# list comprehension comparing two different list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists of namedtuble A and B. Named fields are name, city, river, state, park, school etc.
If element in A and element in B has a match, I need to return an updated tuple. Here is my code:

```
def update_values(A, B):
    ''' update A fields with B fields
    '''
    for n, a in enumerate(A):
        for b in B:
            if a.name == b.name :
                a = a._replace(city = b.city, state = b.state, river=b.river)
                A[n] = a
                break
    return A
```

I was wondering if there is more pythonic way to do this, may be list comprehension.

Comment: If you can use sets (or dictionaries from name to object if your objects are not hashable themselves) this can be done in O(1) instead of O(N^2)

Comment: you need to create a dictionary first for b. Else you'll have a double loop for nothing.

Comment: Do `a` and `b` have other features? If not, could you just do `A[n] = b` instead of doing that `replace`?

Comment: @DeepSpace. Yes..it's a typo. Fixing it.

Comment: @tobias_k..a and b are same tuple, but I don't want to update other fields.

Comment: btw, A and  B are namedtuple.

Comment: @DeepSpace, how would I get this done in O(1).

Comment: Why not provide sample data so we can easily try things? Why make it harder for us to help you?

Comment: Didn't even know `namedtuple` had a `_replace` method. Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def update_values(A, B):
  Bs = { b.name: b for b in B }
  return [ a if a.name not in Bs else a._replace(city=Bs[a.name].city, state=Bs[a.name].state, river=Bs[a.name].river) for a in A ]
```

Comment: I like the comprehension you made. If a and b have the same structure, maybe just replace a with b: [a if a.name not in Bs else Bs[a.name] ]

Comment: @apet it's a good idea, but we have no way to test this hypothesis (OP didn't provide sample data).

Answer (score 1):

Independently of whether you use a list comprehension, you should use a dictionary mapping names to elements from `B` instead of having that inner loop:

```
def update_values(A, B):
    b_by_name = {b.name: b for b in B}
    for n, a in enumerate(A):
        if a.name in b_by_name:
            b = b_by_name[a.name]
            A[n] = a._replace(city = b.city, state = b.state, river=c.river)
    return A
```

However, this will make the conversion to a list comprehension a bit more difficult, as you'd have to repeat the lookup in `b_by_name` each time. (Not a problem computationally, but not nice to read.) Instead, you could use a second "loop" just for binding that value to `b`:

```
def update_values(A, B):
    b_by_name = {b.name: b for b in B}
    return [a._replace(city=b.city, state=b.state, river=b.river) 
            if b is not None else a 
            for a in A for b in [b_by_name.get(a.name)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try building the dictionary for `B` first containing the necessary replacement values, then use `get` to achieve a fast retrieval and unpack the results into your `a._replace` method.

```
def update_values(A, B):
    b_dict = {b.name: {k: getattr(b, k) for k in ('city', 'state', 'river')} for b in B}
    return [a._replace(**b_dict.get(a.name, {})) for a in A]
```

Suppose you have a data sample of such:

```
>>> B
[City(name='Name1', city='City1', state='State1', river='River1', street='Street1'),
 City(name='Name2', city='City2', state='State2', river='River2', street='Street2'),
 City(name='Name3', city='City3', state='State3', river='River3', street='Street3'),
 City(name='Name4', city='City4', state='State4', river='River4', street='Street4'),
 City(name='Name5', city='City5', state='State5', river='River5', street='Street5'),
 City(name='Name6', city='City6', state='State6', river='River6', street='Street6'),
 City(name='Name7', city='City7', state='State7', river='River7', street='Street7'),
 City(name='Name8', city='City8', state='State8', river='River8', street='Street8'),
 City(name='Name9', city='City9', state='State9', river='River9', street='Street9'),
 City(name='Name10', city='City10', state='State10', river='River10', street='Street10'),
 City(name='Name11', city='City11', state='State11', river='River11', street='Street11'),
 City(name='Name12', city='City12', state='State12', river='River12', street='Street12'),
 City(name='Name13', city='City13', state='State13', river='River13', street='Street13'),
 City(name='Name14', city='City14', state='State14', river='River14', street='Street14'),
 City(name='Name15', city='City15', state='State15', river='River15', street='Street15')]

>>> A
[City(name='Name16', city='__C16', state='__S16', river='__R16', street='__ST16'),
 City(name='Name10', city='__C10', state='__S10', river='__R10', street='__ST10'),
 City(name='Name11', city='__C11', state='__S11', river='__R11', street='__ST11'),
 City(name='Name17', city='__C17', state='__S17', river='__R17', street='__ST17'),
 City(name='Name18', city='__C18', state='__S18', river='__R18', street='__ST18'),
 City(name='Name19', city='__C19', state='__S19', river='__R19', street='__ST19'),
 City(name='Name20', city='__C20', state='__S20', river='__R20', street='__ST20'),
 City(name='Name21', city='__C21', state='__S21', river='__R21', street='__ST21'),
 City(name='Name12', city='__C12', state='__S12', river='__R12', street='__ST12'),
 City(name='Name13', city='__C13', state='__S13', river='__R13', street='__ST13'),
 City(name='Name22', city='__C22', state='__S22', river='__R22', street='__ST22'),
 City(name='Name14', city='__C14', state='__S14', river='__R14', street='__ST14'),
 City(name='Name15', city='__C15', state='__S15', river='__R15', street='__ST15'),
 City(name='Name23', city='__C23', state='__S23', river='__R23', street='__ST23'),
 City(name='Name24', city='__C24', state='__S24', river='__R24', street='__ST24')]
```

Running the above function will get you:

```
>>> update_values(A, B)
[City(name='Name16', city='__C16', state='__S16', river='__R16', street='__ST16'),
 City(name='Name10', city='City10', state='State10', river='River10', street='__ST10'),
 City(name='Name11', city='City11', state='State11', river='River11', street='__ST11'),
 City(name='Name17', city='__C17', state='__S17', river='__R17', street='__ST17'),
 City(name='Name18', city='__C18', state='__S18', river='__R18', street='__ST18'),
 City(name='Name19', city='__C19', state='__S19', river='__R19', street='__ST19'),
 City(name='Name20', city='__C20', state='__S20', river='__R20', street='__ST20'),
 City(name='Name21', city='__C21', state='__S21', river='__R21', street='__ST21'),
 City(name='Name12', city='City12', state='State12', river='River12', street='__ST12'),
 City(name='Name13', city='City13', state='State13', river='River13', street='__ST13'),
 City(name='Name22', city='__C22', state='__S22', river='__R22', street='__ST22'),
 City(name='Name14', city='City14', state='State14', river='River14', street='__ST14'),
 City(name='Name15', city='City15', state='State15', river='River15', street='__ST15'),
 City(name='Name23', city='__C23', state='__S23', river='__R23', street='__ST23'),
 City(name='Name24', city='__C24', state='__S24', river='__R24', street='__ST24')]
```

Comment: I think `a._replace(**b_dict.get(a.name, {})` will replace too much. Otherwise you could just use `b_dict.get(a.name, a)` and use the _actual_ `b` from the dict (or `a`).

Comment: I tried `a._replace(**{})` before answering, it doesn't replace anything, hence my suggestion.  I also considered your suggestion but `b` might have more than just `city`, `state` and `river`.

Comment: Ah, did not see that you are only storing those fields in the `b_dict`